# ¿Como convertir una llamada a un rest api de ajax a httpclient ionic/angular?

Tags: javascript, ajax, angular, api, ionic

Buenas noches quiero utilizar una api que se llama besttime.app y en su documentación viene como llamar a ciertos links desde javascript (documentación aquí https://documentation.besttime.app/?javascript#query-venue) el problema es que esto usa el código así:

```
var settings = {
"url": "https://besttime.app/api/v1/venues/ven_51387131543761435650505241346a394a6432395362654a496843",
"data": {
    'api_key_public': 'pub_e11661721b084d36b8f469a2c012e754'
},
"method": "GET" 
};

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
console.log(response);
});
```

Pero yo quiero transformarlo a un servicio en Ionic con httpclient pero no se como enviarlo, tengo esto, pero me da un error porque tengo que enviar el api key public pero no se como enviarlo

```
getOnlyVenue(): Observable<any>{

const headers= new HttpHeaders()
.set('content-type', 'application/json')
.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

let options = {
  headers: headers
}

let settings = {
  "url": "https://besttime.app/api/v1/venues/ven_51387131543761435650505241346a394a6432395362654a496843",
  "data": {
      'api_key_public': 'pub_f9c58ad3dd414040b0721ca7e816971b'
  },
  "method": "GET"
}
/* return this.http.post(settings.url, settings.data); */
return this.http.get<any>(settings.url, options);

}
```

Alguien podría explicarme como pasar de ese código javascript a typescript y funcional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el caso de peticiones GET, el parámetro data de $.ajax corresponde a HttpParams()

```
const url = "https://besttime.app/api/v1/venues/ven_51387131543761435650505241346a394a6432395362654a496843";

const headers= new HttpHeaders().set('content-type', 'application/json')
    .set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

const params = new HttpParams().append('api_key_public','pub_f9c58ad3dd414040b0721ca7e816971b');
return this.http.get(url, {params, headers});
```

Espero que te sirva. Un saludo.

Comment: Muchas gracias si me funcionó lo de los params, lo único es que los headers no los aceptaba así que los omití